# ios 6 emulator - remote debugging, and how to empty device cashing

Tags: javascript, safari, ios6

I am debugging Node.js server code from iOS emulator using remote debugger in iOS 6 Safari.

The thing is that I have to "Reset Content and Settings" to force a refreshed from the server.

The question is then, how to force iOS to force a refresh - "Safari / Develop / Disable Caches" is not working?

On the iOS simolator you can do "iOS Simolator / Reset Content and Settings" but are you really surpose to do this on each refresh on a server page change?

Thanks

Comment: I posted an answer to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218123/how-to-disable-cache-on-ipad-safari/17689377#17689377